# How can write a poll or epoll server in Golang?

Tags: go

In Golang, if we want to write a socket server, we can write like this :

```
listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "****")
for {
    conn, err := listen.Accept()
    ...
}
```

`net.Listen()` include create `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, and uses `epoll` in implementation.

in CPP, if we want to write a server, we can chose to use `select`, `poll` or `epoll` freely , so my question is: in Golang, how can I write a server using `select` or `poll` instead of `epoll.

Comment: Why do you want to use select or poll directly?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The runtime network poller is already an epoll server (or whatever polling mechanism is most efficient on the given platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with **system calls** used during connection creation; you will find the [syscalls package](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall) useful for what you need to do where you can choose to use these system calls as you need. It consists of all the system calls you will need.

I also found this example [gist](https://gist.github.com/Lisprez/7b52f4a55cd0fcf96324b5f02b865e54) which you can reference for making your own implementation using **poll** or **select**.